# Finding values of x for logarithm

Tags: calculus, logarithms

The question is to find the numbers of x which satisfy the equation.

$$
\log_x10=\log_4100.
$$

I have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln10}{\ln x} &= \frac{\ln 100}{\ln 4} \\
\frac{\ln10}{\ln x} &= \frac{2\ln 10}{2\ln 2}
\end{align*}

What would I do after this step?

Comment: Bring the equation to the form $ln(x)=...$. Can you do that? Afterwards use the inverse function of the logarithm, which is $e^x$

Comment: could you show me the steps?

Comment: Why not use change of base to change to log base 10 instead of ln? That would easily cancel out the 10 and 100, making the problem rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

All right. 
First multiply by $ln(x)$ and by $ln(2)$. You get

$ln(10)ln(2)=ln(10)ln(x)$

Now divide by $ln(10)$. This gives you

$ln(2)=ln(x)$.

Now you apply the exponential function on both sides to get rid of the logarithm:

$\underbrace{e^{ln(x)}}_{=x}=\underbrace{e^{ln(2)}}_{=2}$

So $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find an $x$ such that $$\log_x10=\log_4100$$ is satisfied.

Continuing from your steps:

$\frac{\ln10}{\ln x}=\frac{\ln100}{\ln4}$

$\frac{\ln10}{\ln x}=\frac{2\ln10}{2\ln2}$

$\ln x=\frac{(2\ln2)(\ln10)}{2\ln10}$

$\ln x=\ln2$

$x=2$

Comment: why would lnx=ln2 in the second last step?

Comment: like how did you get ln2?

Comment: The fraction $\frac{(2ln2)(ln10)}{2ln10}$ can be simplified by dividing by $2ln10$.